# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `string` supplied to `DetailField`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

when

```
children: PropTypes.string
```

It's showing error

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `DetailField`, expected `string`.
```

when

```
children: PropTypes.object
```

It's showing error

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `string` supplied to `DetailField`, expected `object`.
```

And if I try to do this, I don't know if it's valid or not

```
children: PropTypes.object && PropTypes.string
```

It shows

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `DetailField`, expected `string`.
```

What should I do?

Comment: please provide your relevant component implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check for one of two prop types, object or string:

```
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.object,
  PropTypes.string,
])
```

Please check out the [prop-types README](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md) for more information.